# wcout not writing wide character out to command prompt

Tags: c++, windows, internationalization

I am attempting to write the following character out in windows command prompt: ｭ (U+FF6D).

I am able to see the character get written out using WriteConsoleW. I am also able to see the character if i use WideCharToMultiByte using the CP_ACP code page (chcp returns 932: Japanese). However, when I attempt to use regular wcout on the same string which WriteConsoleW successfully prints, it chokes.

When I execute setlocale(LC_ALL, "") it prints English_UnitedStates.1252 (the default code page that I had when I installed).

Why is wcout failing when the others are succeeding?

**Note: I rebooted the machine to change its system locale to Japan Japanese**

Comment: Do you ever call `std::wcout.imbue()` to change `wcout`'s code page?

Comment: That worked. But why is wcout's code page different when I reset the system locale? Post an explanation and you get easy points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default locale for C++ iostreams is always the "C" locale. From the C++03 standard, §27.4.2.3/4:

> `locale getloc() const;`
>
> If no locale has been imbued, a copy of the global C++ locale, `locale()`, in effect at the time of construction.

From §22.1.1.2/1-2:

> `locale() throw();`
>
> Default constructor: a snapshot of the current global locale.
>
> Constructs a copy of the argument last passed to `locale::global(locale&)`, if it has been called; else, the resulting facets have virtual function semantics identical to those of `locale::classic()`.

From §22.1.1.5/4-6:

> `static const locale& classic();`
>
> The "C" locale.
>
> Returns: A locale that implements the classic "C" locale semantics, equivalent to the value `locale("C")`.
>
> Notes: This locale, its facets, and their member functions, do not change with time.

As `std::cout` and `std::wcout` have static storage duration, they are guaranteed to be initialized before `main` is called, and consequently will *always* have the "C" locale at application startup; i.e., there is no point early enough in execution that one can call `locale::global` and change the default locale for `std::cout` and `std::wcout`. Thus, you must always imbue the global streams yourself if you want to use a non-default code page.

Comment: So I guess that this is a windows specific question then. At no point have I called cout.imbue within my application, however it can still handle the code page character. I was under the assumption (yes assumption evil thing) that wcout would have imbue'ed the same locale.

Answer (score 0):

`wcout` is created *before* any code in `main` executes. By the time you call `setlocale`, `wcout` is already there, ready to do its thing. It makes no attempt at tracking subsequent changes you might make with `setlocale`, so it continues to use the default instead of whatever you set with `setlocale`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but if I my machine booted up with a locale which is capable of printing the character (U+FF6D) has a mapped character to CP 932. I guess my question is how is the default locale for wcout defined?

Comment: @bogertron : My answer addresses that aspect of the question.