# Using getCurrentDirectoryW Doesn't Read Non-locale Characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, wchar-t

I use the following code to read current directory in Windows 7. The current directory is C:\特斯塔敌人. The current locale is English(EN). I used getCurrentDirectoryW with the idea that it will properly read the directory path since the function is using unicode:

```
wchar_t w_pcRootLocation[MAX_PATH+100];
GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, w_pcRootLocation);
wcout << w_pcRootLocation << endl;
```

MAX_PATH is defined in WinDef.h and is equal to 260.

When I print the output to the console using wcout, what I see is only the following:

```
C:\
```

The Chinese characters are not read apparently. What is the issue here and how do I read the path in Unicode properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger and you'll see that `GetCurrentDirectoryW` is working just fine. The problem is with the `wcout`. (In other words, the Chinese characters were properly read. The problem occurs when *writing* them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetCurrentDirectoryW() is likely working fine.  It's the next bit that's got problems.

std::wcout is going to use the "C" locale.  You're going to need to adjust (`imbue()`) it appropriately to display your out of codepage glyphs.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750884/wcout-not-writing-wide-character-out-to-command-prompt) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have solved the issue for wcout...

[wcout not writing wide character out to command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750884/wcout-not-writing-wide-character-out-to-command-prompt)

It's worth checking with a debugger to make sure `w_pcRootLocation` does contain the characters.